# Start headless chrome in incognito

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-headless, incognito-mode

Under SpecFlow/Selenium, I'm starting Chrome like this:

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--headless", "--window-size=1920,1080", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-extensions", "--no-sandbox", "-incognito");

    var svc = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    svc.Start();

    Context.Driver = new ChromeDriver(svc, options);
```

As the `-incognito` flag on the Chrome executable starts the browser in incognito mode I was thinking this was do the same for headless mode. I was wrong. Can it be done with headless? If so, how?

I have also tried `--incognito` and `incognito` as well as placing the flag at different indices within the `AddArguments()` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D'oh! Turns out I was missing a single `-`...

```
"--incognito"
```